# GitBash uninstalled automatically in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, octave, git-bash

I am using Windows 10 and there was an update for the OS and I installed those updates but right after updating, GitBash automatically got uninstalled from my machine.

Below are my questions regarding this,

1. Should I be worried about this auto uninstallation ? If so what
   checks should I do to my system ?
2. Also is there any other way to know the reason for this uninstallation, may be system log ?

The windows update is - [KB4487029](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4487029/windows-10-update-kb4487029)

The one thing of my concern is,  **is there is any virus in my system** :| because of which this uninstall happened after the update.

Also after this update a few softwares installation date changed to today's date. I have installed PyCharm & Octave, 2 weeks back but after the windows update even their installation date in the uninstall programs menu changed to today's date :|

Comment: Windows 10 seems to do very bad things sometimes. Perhaps this helps: https://www.howtogeek.com/243581/windows-10-may-delete-your-programs-without-asking/

Comment: @DodgyCodeException thanks that helped for the uninstallation, but I'm still not sure why there is an update in the installation dates for Octave & PyCharm. but thanks again !

Comment: Have the version numbers of Octave and PyCharm actually been automatically updated or are they the same version?

Comment: they are still the same